# Upload a dynamic php-image via facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, image, dynamic, upload

I'd like to upload an imgage via the Facebook API. The point is, this image is created with php.

```
//$file = '\image.php?name=$name&result=$complete';
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$args = array('message' => 'Message');
$args['source'] = "@" . "back.jpg";

try {
    $data = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $args);
    echo "Das Foto wurde in deinem Profil gepostet.";
} 
catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```

This works, but i dont want to upload the back.jpg, i want to upload the generated image from $file.
If i try i get the error:

> CurlException: 26: failed creating formpost data

Does someone have an solution?

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly you can't use wrappers when sending files via curl, so path to script creating images won't work. There should be absolute system path when sending file. You should first save generated image to temporary file then send it via `@/path/to/tmp/file.jpg` and delete temporary file.

Answer (score 0):

Just give the full file path to the image like:

```
$filePath = 'images/back.jpg';

$args['source']= '@' . realpath($filePath);
```

Just try and it might work for you...